# SQL exclude on multiple criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my first post and I am new to SQL.

I have some data where the ID number begins with "0 thru 9", "C", "F", "E" and "H". My issue is I need to exclude all the ID numbers that begin with any of the letter values and also equal a particular word in another column, such as "Apple". However, I need to keep all the letter value ID's that contain for instance "Orange".

Data:

```
12345 Apple
56789 Apple
14569 Orange
14569 Apple
C2456 Apple
C2456 Orange
F1234 Apple
F1234 Orange
```

Needed data:

```
12345 Apple
56789 Apple
14569 Orange
14569 Apple
C2456 Orange
F1234 Orange
```

How would I do this in my where clause?

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
select *
from YourTable
where (left(lower(ID),1) like '%[a-z]%' and Column2 = 'Orange')
OR (left(ID,1) like '%[0-9]%')
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks sooo much!

Comment: No problem @MSquared20. Remember to [help others who may find your question useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Have a good one!